# For Vaadin application how can I integrate with js file

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I have created an vaadin application but it requires javascript integration.How can I add .js file into vaadin application?

Answer (score 0):

For Vaadin 6 you should be able to use the executeJavascript method in Window like so:

```
getWindow().executeJavaScript("alert(\"Hello JavaScript\");");
```